# How to copy an array in another array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I faced a problem in my JS function...
In this function I tried to keep `localState` value in two other arrays (localState0,localState1) and at the end of my loops when I tried to reset localState value, It's not working cuz in this part `localState[cellI][cellJ] = turn(localStates, val);` both `localState` and `localState0` changed and I don't know why!

```
var minMax = function(val){
    var localState = state.slice()
    var states = []
    var evals = []

    for(k =0; k< 16; k++){
        var  localState0 = []
        localState0 = localState.slice()
        var cellI = converter(k)[0]
        var cellJ = converter(k)[1]
        if (localStates[cellI][cellJ] == ""){
            localState[cellI][cellJ] = turn(localStates, val);
            var localState1 = []
            localState1 = localState.slice()
            for(var w=0; w<16; w++){
                var cellII = converter(w)[0]
                var cellJJ = converter(w)[1]
                if (localState[cellII][cellJJ] == ""){
                    localState[cellII][cellJJ] = turn(localStates, val);
                    states.push(localState);
                    evals.push(eval(localState, val))
                    localState = localState1
                }
            }
        }
        localState = localState0
    }
return states
}
```

*turn function return a string like this `"X" or "O"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `localState0 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localState))` instead `localState0 = localState.slice()`